# How to pause player motion during an air attack animation in Godot 4?

Tags: animation, godot, godot-4, gravity

So I am very new to Game Dev, and I am running into a problem that seems like it should have a simple answer. Unfortunately, I have not been able to figure it out.

I am creating a 2d side scroller. I have incorporated a quick and heavy attack the player can execute on the ground, and a set of attacks when the player is jumping. However, when the air attacks animate, the player continues falling to the ground - often landing before the attack animation finishes. I would like to lock the players position in the air until the animation finishes, and then allow the player to fall it is complete. I haven't figured out how to stop and make the player hover in place during the animation. I've searched around for a solution, but haven't been able to find an explanation.

This doesn't seem like a particularly unique concept, and I am hoping somebody has some sort of similar experience. I would be happy to provide any extra information needed. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your player character is a `CharacterBody2D`, you are in charge of moving it.

For example, you might be adding gravity to the velocity, something like this would suffice:

```
velocity += gravity * delta
```

---

So temporarly disabling gravity is a matter of setting a flag and checking it before doing the gravity computation. For example, we can declare:

```
bool _attacking := false
```

On your attack code you set:

```
_attacking = true
```

And you might want to connect a method to the `finished` signal of your animation player, so you can there reset the flag:

```
_attacking = false
```

And then we can check:

```
if not _attacking:
    velocity += gravity * delta
```

As alternative, you might check which is the current animation of the animation player, and use that to know if the player is attacking.